# java regex to find two '%d' doesn't work

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String:

```
String filename = "somefile%dh.mm a%d.txt";
```

to be sure that filename contains two `%d`, I use this regex:

```
System.out.println((filename.matches("%d.*%d")));
```

but it returns false. What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to match the whole word, including characters before and after the two `%d`:

```
filename.matches(".*%d.*%d.*")
```

Comment: Correct, filename.matches("somefile%d.*%d\\.txt") returns true

Answer (score 1):

It returns False, because [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) compares the complete input string against the pattern.

To check if your string contains a pattern use the [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method.

```
System.out.println((filename.find("%d.*%d")));
```

This will return true if the pattern occurs somewhere in your string.